# Update user status with Socket.io fails

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, socket.io, mean-stack

I have tried the whole day to get a normally very simple task done and failed. 
What I try to do is to update the "online-status" in a Chat-application via socket.io.

I actually have a common method that gets applied when the user logs in or out, from this common method I call a `socket.emit(updateuser, true/false)` depending on whether the user logs in or off, with the purpose that the server informs all the other clients to update their view accordingly.

The method where the socket.emit is called looks as follows.

```
setUserStatus(status: boolean): void {
    const data = {
      status: status
    };
    this.http.put<{email: any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/user/changeStatus/' + this._userMail, data)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.socket.emit('changeStatus', { // Here the logic for informing the clients is called
          email: response.email,
          status: status
        });
      });
```

I know that it does not make sense to make a REST Request and the also make a socket.io call but that's another topic :D

On the server-side, the server then informs all the other clients in the namespace to update the online status accordingly

```
io.of('/chat').on('connection', (socket) = > {
        console.log('Chat Socket connected on server');
        socket.on('new-message', (message) = > {
            io.of('/chat').emit("ChatMessage", message);
        });
        // THIS IS THE METHOD I AM TALKING ABOUT - CHANGE STATUS! 
        socket.on('changeStatus', status = > {
            console.log('CHANGE STATUS EMIT: UPDATE STATUS ON SERVER FOR ' + status.email);
            io.of('/chat').emit('userLogged', {
                email: status.email,
                status: status.status
            });
        });
```

Then I update the user status in the ngOnInit of my userList component (Angular) as soon as the subscription gets "called"

```
this.logEventSub = this.chatService.newUser.subscribe(user = > {
    console.log('REASSIGNING STATUS for user ' + user.email);
    this.users.find(eachUser = > eachUser.email === user.email).status = user.status;
});
```

The problem is, that it seems that just the client who emits the request actually updated its own status. The other clients do not get the request from the server-side. I really do not know why because as far I read the command io.of.emit.... is the right one to inform ALL the connected clients - actually, I also tried some other commands but it did not help.

What is even more curious is the fact that it seemed to work one or two times - but I do not know what was actually different - in the console, I saw that the client got the first request when he himself logged in, and then also the second when the second client logged in. A second try it did not work out again, and I could not reproduce it.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using namespaces instead of rooms. I cannot be sure without seeing the `.on('connection')` function. You should be using rooms and broadcasting to the whole room.

Are you sure that all your client sockets `this.socket` are connected to the namespace via `this.socket = io('/chat');` ?

`socket.to('chat').emit('hello');` will emit to everyone in that room except the socket owner (the one joining in this case). See https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room.

I would need to see more in order to be certain.

Comment: I have added the "connection" part - in addition as you can see in the "new-message" part - there i am using the same command for sending the messages between the clients and it works!!

Comment: can I see the declaration of `this.chatService.newUser` as well, or can you put an example on stackblitz ? I don't see anything that goes wrong here.

Comment: Yes the declaration is identical to this one used for new messages and goes like this:  newUser = this.socket.fromEvent<any>('userLogged'); - it is very strange though - because as i said, sometimes it works, and sometimes it does not ! I do not know exactly why, but it seems that it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of TypeScript which makes me a lot a headache